# Need AutoHotkey scripts

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking for someone that knows AutoHotkey that will help me create the following scripts on Windows 7;

1) Minimize window (using control/dot)
2) Closing active window (using control/left arrow)
3) Closing all windows (using control/right arrow)

I've looked at their web site but know nothing about programing so I don't understand the symbols or how to use them. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Carlos

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5):

The [AutoHotkey (AHK)](http://autohotkey.com) scripting language is similar to [BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC), and as such is relatively easy to learn. If you are looking to get a general understand of how AHK works, the [Tutortial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) is a great start.

Anyway, the following should do what you want:

- Minimize the active window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>:

  ```
  ^.::WinMinimize, A
  ```
- Close the active window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>:

  ```
  ^Left::WinClose, A
  ```
- Close all windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>:

  ```
  ^Right::
     GroupAdd, AllWindows
     WinClose, ahk_group AllWindows
     return
  ```

---

Documentation:

- [Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [WinMinimize](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm)
- [WinClose](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm)
- [GroupAdd](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm)
- [Return](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  It's really going to help a lot.  How can I assign points to you for such a fine job?